# Where to upload the Linux VM PEM File in Azure to get the path?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine

[image]

Here it is asking PEM File path. Where we need to upload it for getting the path.

Do we need to create storage account for that PEM file, which incurs additional cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where to upload the Linux VM PEM File in Azure to get the path?

When creating a `Linux VM` with **SSH** authentication, the private key file will be downloaded to your local machine.

**My private key**

[image]

1. Kindly copy the file path of the **linux-privatekey.pem** and paste it into the **Copy and execute SSH command** section in the Azure Portal. This will generate the SSH command with the private key path.
2. Generate a public key on your local machine by using **PuttyGen** or **ssh-keygen**.

[image]

3. Copy and save the public key in the same path where you saved the private key earlier.

[image]

4. Upload the same public key to the **Azure portal by navigating to Azure Portal > Select your VM > Reset password > Add SSH public key > use existing public key >** paste the public key here.

[image]

5. Finally, go to **Native SSH**, paste the private key file path under **Copy and execute SSH command**, and copy the following command: **SSH to VM with specified private key**. Run this command in the terminal to connect to the VM.

[image]